# Access html loaded in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to access the HTML-code loaded into a variable. Precisely, I'd like to retain elements with a specific class. Here's my code:

```
        $.get('../someHtml.html', function( my_var ) {
            div.innerHTML = my_var;
            var my_var2 = div.$("my_class"); //that doesn't work
            }, 'html' );
```

You see, I want to store all elements of the variable div with class `my_class` in the variable `my_var2`.

Comment: Throw away all that code and use `load` instead of `get` (see below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
var my_var2 = $(my_var).find('.my_class');
```

Comment: Thanks! there's anything else but 'find'? Just interested.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) instead of `.get()`. It allows you to supply a filter.

The following uses a dummy jQuery div to hold the result, but it can be loaded into any jQuery element:

```
var $div = $('<div>');
$div.load('../someHtml.html .my_class');
```

Answer (score 1):

try `find()`:

```
$.get('../someHtml.html', function( my_var ) {
            div.innerHTML = my_var;
            var my_var2 = $(my_var).find('.my_class');
            }, 'html' );
```